# Left & Right Background CSS in div changes body content container width

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I put this together to display a background on the left and right side of a website.

Now with this in place the body container is appearing much wider than it was before. Why would this be?

Can anybody see what isn't good code in the below?

```
   div#multi-background {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url(http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0834/6311/t/2/assets/right-1.png), url(http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0834/6311/t/2/assets/left-1.png);
        background-position: center right, top left;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
    //Happens when the screen size is >= 481px
     div#multi-background {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url(http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0834/6311/t/2/assets/right-1.png), url(http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0834/6311/t/2/assets/left-1.png);
        background-position: center right, top left;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
     }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 481px) {
    //Happens when the screen size is <= 481px
     div#multi-background {
       background-image: none;
     }
    }
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/timsalabim/1mk097vb/8/

Comment: Can you post the HTML that goes with the page too please?

Comment: Better if you can put them into jsfiddle. It will be easier for others to check out the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "body container is wider"? Is the `<body>` wider with the background than without?

Comment: Yes. As soon as I add the above, my body gets fatter with white space

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, this would be the code you want:

```css
#multi-background {
    height: 700px;
    background-image: url(http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0834/6311/t/2/assets/right-1.png), url(http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0834/6311/t/2/assets/left-1.png);
    background-position: center right, top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) {
/*Happens when the screen size is bigger than 481px */
 #multi-background {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0834/6311/t/2/assets/right-1.png), url(http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0834/6311/t/2/assets/left-1.png);
    background-position: center right, top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 481px) {
/*Happens when the screen size is lower than 481px*/
#multi-background {
   background-image: none;
 }
}
```

```html
<body><div id="multi-background"></div>
```

The comments were not written with "/*" and "*/". There were problems with @media declaration and height issues for more than 481 px.

Hope it helps.